# Генерация n простых чисел

Tags: алгоритм, простые-числа

Нужно ввести число n и сгенерировать n простых чисел. Есть ли какой-нибудь алгоритм для этого? Нашел только решето Эратосфена, но оно не подходит для моего задания.

Comment: Какие дополнительные условия? Почему не годится решето? Можно, в конце-концов, просто прошить таблицу и брать n первых чисел из нее :)

Comment: Решето вычисляет все простые числа на промежутке от 1 до n, если я введу 10, я получу не 10 простых чисел, а 4(2,3,5,7)

Comment: А кто мешает работать дальше? :)

Comment: Либо вы меня не понимаете, либо я вас

Comment: Псевдокод:
функция подсчет(n) {
   какие-то операции
}
подсчет(5) 
>>  2, 3, 5, 7, 11
подсчет(15)
>> 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069023/13785489 - тут приводится верхняя граница для N-ного простого числа. Вычислив ее, вы сможете просто запустить решето от этой границы, после чего взять первые N элементов от результата.

Answer (score 4):

Простейший вариант на С++:

```
bool is_prime(int k)
{
    for(int i = 3; i*i <= k; i+= 2)
        if (k%i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}

vector<int> primes(int n)
{
    vector<int> v;
    if (n >= 1) v.push_back(2);
    for(int k = 3; v.size() < n; k += 2)
        if (is_prime(k)) v.push_back(k);
    return v;
}
```

Вот через решето Эратосфена, просто с запасом сверху. Его можно и уменьшить...

```
vector<int> eratos(int n)
{
    vector<int> r;
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        if (n == 1) r.push_back(2);
        return r;
    }
    int m = (n+6)*(log(n)+log(log(n)));

    vector<int> v(m,1);
    v[0] = v[1] = 0;
    int k = 2;
    while(k*k <= m)
    {
        for(int i = 2*k; i < m; i+=k) v[i] = 0;
        while(v[++k] == 0);
    }
    for(int i = 2; r.size() < n; ++i)
        if (v[i]) r.push_back(i);
    return r;
}
```

Примерное сравнение времен вычисления для разных `n` на моей машине

```
n                 100    1000     10000     100000
primes(), mks       9     170      4500     131000
eratos(), mks      12      54       650       7400
```

Answer (score 0):

вот

```
from itertools import islice



def primes():
    if hasattr(primes, "D"):
        D = primes.D
    else:
        primes.D = D = {}

    def pr():
        q = 2
        while True:
            if q not in D:
                yield q
                D[q * q] = [q]
            else:
                for p in D[q]:
                    D.setdefault(p + q, []).append(p)
                del D[q]
            q += 1
    return pr()


n = int(input())
spisok = list(islice(primes(), 0, n))
```